# Generating function for 3 -core partitions: Part II

Tags: co.combinatorics, soft-question, partitions, elementary-proofs

Let $\lambda$ be an integer partition: $\lambda=(\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\dots\geq0)$. Further, let $h_u$ denote the [hook-length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula#Example) of the cell $u$.

We call $\lambda$ a $t$-core partition if none of its hooks $h_u$ equals $t$.  Define $c_t(n)$ to be the number of partitions of $n$ that are $t$-core partitions. It's well-known that 
$$\sum_{n\geq0}c_t(n)\,q^n=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-q^{tk})^t}{1-q^k}.$$
For example, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_2(n)\,q^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^{\binom{k+1}2}$.

Now, consider only those partitions of $n$ with **odd parts** and let $O_t(n)$ be the number of such partitions that are $t$-cores.

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
>   $$\sum_{n\geq1}O_3(n)\,q^n=(1+q)\sum_{k\geq1}q^{k^2}.$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose the partition with $k$ parts $\lambda=\{\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq\dots\geq\lambda_k\geq \lambda_{k+1}=0\}$ is a partition with only odd parts. Then we have $\lambda_i-\lambda_{i+1}$ is even for all $i\leq k-1$ and odd for $i=k$. Using the same characterization I mentioned in the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312837/generating-function-for-3-core-partitions/312840#312840) we see that the sequence
$\{\lambda_1-\lambda_2,\lambda_2-\lambda_3,\dots,\lambda_{k}-\lambda_{k+1}\}$ for such a $3$-core has to be equal to $\{2,2,\dots,2,1\}$ or $\{2,2,\dots,2,0,1\}$. The first case is a partition with size $k^2$ and the second has size $1+k^2$ which implies the generating function
$$\sum_{n\geq1}O_3(n)\,q^n=\sum_{k\geq1}(q^{k^2}+q^{k^2+1}).$$